# The MySQL request is very slow

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database with many tables. I need to generate a report by selecting data from different tables. I make the following request:

```
SELECT finance, DR, DATE_Z_1, DATE_Z_2, P_CEL, DS1, VISIT_POL, VISIT_HOM FROM zap 
JOIN pacient ON zap.id = pacient.zap_id 
JOIN z_sl ON zap.id = z_sl.zap_id 
JOIN sl ON z_sl.id = sl.z_sl_id 
JOIN pers ON pacient.ID_PAC = pers.ID_PAC 
JOIN reestr ON zap.reestr_id = reestr.id 
WHERE (z_sl.IDSP IN (29,30)) AND (IDDOKT = "123") 
AND (sl.OTKAZ_I_TYPE IS NULL) AND (z_sl._SANK = 0) 
GROUP BY zap.id, pers.ID_PAC
```

The request can be processed in about 10 seconds. And I need to make 200 such requests, substituting the required identifier in the "IDDOKT" parameter. This will take more than 30 minutes. This doesn't suit me. Where is the mistake? What can be done? Help me please.

An index has been created for all parameters for comparison when joining. In addition, an index was created on the "IDDOKT" column.

For example, indexes "sl" table:

```
Name: z_sl_id
Field: `z_sl_id`
Index Type: NORMAL
Index method: BTREE

Name: IDDOKT_index
Field: `IDDOKT`(11)
Index Type: NORMAL
Index method: BTREE
```

Result of EXPLAIN command:

[image: EXPLAIN command]

Result of EXPLAIN command after added index (column `ID_PAC`, table `pers`):

[image: EXPLAIN command with index ID_PAC]

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` command to analyze the performance of your query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html#:~:text=The%20EXPLAIN%20statement%20provides%20information,about%20the%20statement%20execution%20plan.

Comment: I completed the EXPLAIN command, but I don’t know what to do with it. Please tell me.

Comment: To optimize the query with the output of `EXPLAIN` (or `DESCRIBE`) command, you can see the last row involves 562761 rows on the table `pers`, and the Extra column stated: *Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)*, to optimize hash joins:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hash-joins.html

Comment: I added index (column `ID_PAC` table `pers`) but the situation didn't change.  The last row of the `EXPLAIN` command now excludes 562761 lines. But the query execution time did not decrease.
​

Comment: What if adding index on `reestr.id` column? I can see that it's `PRIMARY KEY` but let's just try a few thing.

Comment: It became faster, but not by much

Comment: This query does not make much sense as yoi group by two columns, but do not aggregate any of the columns!

Comment: Please post TEXT results of EVERY TABLE used in the posted query - SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for analysis.